# Laravel filament, is there any way to mutate TextColumn value in table?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-filament

How to get only one value in the filament where table with hasMany relationship?

I have two DB tables:

`products`

| id | sku |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | SKU_1 |
| 2 | SKU_2 |

`product_descriptions`

| id | product_id | translation_id | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | Opel |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | Vauxhall |

In my Product model I have `hasMany` relationship

```
public function productDescriptions(): HasMany
{
   return $this->hasMany(ProductDescription::class);
}
```

When I do `Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('productDescriptions.name')` it return all values separated by comma. In my example "Opel, Vauxhall"

Is there any way to manipulate/mutate return value using callback? Let say, return only first value "Opel"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [calculated states](https://filamentphp.com/docs/2.x/tables/columns/getting-started#calculated-state).

```
Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('productDescriptions.name')
   ->getStateUsing( function (Model $record){
      return $record->productDescriptions()->first()?->name;
   });
```